# Protection against XSS using a tiny virtual-machine in browser

Tags: web-development, browser, virtual-machine

I'm working on a web framework that makes surveys. It has an expression manager which lets admin users run code on the client as Javascript. There could be a potential XSS problem when there's more than one admin, as is the case for universities. So, instead of compiling expressions to Javascript, what about compiling them to a bitcode and have a tiny VM in the browser to check for XSS? Do you think it could give better protection than just analyzing Javascript?

Comment: So you are allowing users to add javascript that gets passed to other users & evaled?

Comment: @user60812 Yes, the framework allows admin users to add "expressions", compiled to Javascript, to be added to a survey or a question within a survey.

Answer (score 2):

Building your own "VM" could be a pretty heavy lift.

Just treat any code you didn't write as part of an external application. Execute the script off-page, ideally in a sandbox on the server. (Use a spidermonkey plugin or a node sandbox.) At the very least, execute untrusted scripts in a frame on a totally separate domain.

Comment: That depends, a small VM might not be such a big project. Here's one in Ruby in 150 LOC: https://github.com/txus/microvm

Additional architectural dependencies is not an option because of the user-base.

I will investigate the possibility to run scripts elsewhere, but it depends on how much they need to interact with other stuff.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt Not sure I understand the "additional architecture" comment. ... Is this an individually/locally deployed (on-premise) app?

Comment: Both. It's an open-source PHP web-application, but you can buy support and hosting for it.

Comment: I can update my answer if it help; but, for on-premise applications that the customer customizes, it's perfectly acceptable to leave XSS concerns *on their customizations* in their hands. Bear in mind that many *very expensive, very robust* products are stable and secure out-of-the-box, but *the customer* is responsible for security issues that they introduce through their own processes, mismanagement, and customizations.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem in this case arises in a certain setting, namely when there are more than one admin user. I think the framework should offer a possibility to handle this scenario safely. Thanks for your feedback!